# seaborn unknown line on barchart

Tags: seaborn, bar-chart

Below in the picture their is a brown barplot and on that plot their is a dark brown small line at the end.

Its not possible to post the exact code because its many thousands of line. So my question is what parameter could be coursing this?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several values corresponding to the category `f` which are averaged together and the bar is the 95%CI around that mean.

If you want to hide the CI, pass `ci=None` to `barplot()`

Comment: Thank you very much I was mistakenly looking for some kind of second hidden axis I thought I was going crazy for a minute!

Comment: Out of interested how come the CI is only showing on that one bar and not the rest? Thanks

Comment: impossible to know without looking at the data

Comment: OK I understand, Thanks again